# Accidentally used -S when creating my tmux session instead of -s, where is my session?

Tags: tmux

I created a new session of tmux, intending to use the -s flag to name it, but confused the command with -S which specifies a socket. I know the session is alive, because the processes I started in it are still running. But when I try to list running sessions it does not appear. Where is my session and how do I recover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tmux` option `-S` means socket path (from `man tmux`):

```
 -S socket-path
               Specify a full alternative path to the server socket.  If -S is specified, the default
               socket directory is not used and any -L flag is ignored.
```

So you have to find out the parent directory where `tmux` was run with
`-S` option and pass this option to `tmux` to point it to the
alternative socket path. You could for example find `PID` of the
`tmux` process:

```
$ ps aux | grep  '[t]mux'
ja       15121  0.0  0.0  20252  2236 pts/6    S+   00:44   0:00 tmux -S new
```

And then check this process `cwd` in `/proc` like this:

```
$ ls -l /proc/15121/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ja users 0 Aug 19 00:52 /proc/15121/cwd -> /home/ja
```

And then to refer to this `tmux` session:

```
$ tmux  -S /home/ja/new ls
0: 1 windows (created Sat Aug 19 00:44:46 2017) [212x65] (attached)
```